# Where to store DbContext in a asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-first, software-design

I think I'm facing an architecture problem I can solve:

I'm developing a web applicationusing entity framework code first (v4.3 beta1).
Also, there are a few web services published.

In a separate Class Library, I have the DbContext and al, the entities. This library is referenced by the web application, obviuously.

In the "Data" library, I have a static property to hold de context:

```
namespace MMOrpheus.Lib
{
    public class Context
    {
        public static MMOrpheusDB MMO
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["MMOEntities"] == null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["MMOEntities"] = new MMOrpheusDB();
                }
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["MMOEntities"] as MMOrpheusDB;
            }
            set
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["MMOEntities"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MMOrpheusDB inherit from DbContext.

So the problem is I someway feel this is not right. Among other things, I don't think this Context class should be using System.Web!

Any suggestions on how to organize this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The answer to your question is not a simple one.*

First of all I suggest, you use a **dependency injection & inversion of control** framework (StructureMap,Unity,...).

If you are going to store your **DbContext**, using an **IOC** will make it so easy. You can define **lifetime** of your **context**. I normally go with **PerRequest** life time. *One instance of DbContext for each web request*. DBContext starts with a request and ends with it.

***But there is no need to go with this pattern.*** You can simply **start** you **context** when you need it and **dispose** it after using it.

If you prefer the first approach, search for *Domain Driven Design, IOC, Unit Of Work, Repository Pattern & etc.*